# On parameterizing $x^3+y^3+z^3=2$ and higher power versions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

There are the nice and simple identities,

$$(2x+1)^2 + (2x^2+2x-1)^2 - (2x^2+2x)^2 = 2$$

$$ (6x^3+1)^3 + (-6x^3+1)^3 + (-6x^2)^3 = 2$$

$$ (8x^5-2x)^4 + (8x^4+1)^4 + (8x^4-1)^4 - (8x^5+2x)^4 - (4x^2)^4 = 2$$

$$ (-8x^6+2x)^5 + (-8x^6-2x)^5 + (8x^5+1)^5 + (-8x^5+1)^5 + 2(8x^6)^5 = 2$$

with the first two presumably discovered by multiple authors, while $k=4$ is by Seiji Tomita and $k=5$ by Ajai Choudhry.

> **Q:** Can we find the $k=6$ or $k=7$ version?

**P.S.** Jarek Wrobleski found,

$$(1 + 3^5\sqrt3\, x^7)^7 + (1 - 3^5\sqrt3\, x^7)^7 + (3x - 3^6x^8)^7 + (-3x - 3^6x^8)^7 + 2(3^6x^8)^7 = 2$$

though since this is a *Diophantine* problem and to be consistent with the rest, terms should be integers.

Comment: what are the full rules

Comment: @shaihorowitz: Well, to keep it simple, the number of terms on the LHS should be as small as possible. For example, for $k=5$, it has only six, counting the last term twice. And, for even $k$, operator may be add or minus.

Comment: hmm hard to prove least possible terms interesting problem